# Enforcing sparsity on probability

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, optimization, regularization, sparse

I am trying to induce a probability distribution $Q$ by optimizing an objective function and am wondering how can one encourage sparsity for $Q$ while keeping the optimization convex.

In particular, there $m$ distributions: $q_i$ for $i=1... m$, where each $q_i$ lies, say, in a 10-dimensional simplex. Given certain observations, we learn $Q=\{q_1,...,q_m\}$ as

$F(Q) =  \min_{q_i, i=1...m} \sum_i f(q_i)$

where $f$ is convex. This is all well and good. Now, we also want to encourage sparsity for $q_i$ i.e. we want most of the probabilities within $q_i$ to be zero.

I am wondering if it is possible to device a regularization for $q_i$ to achieve this while keeping the optimization convex.